# Finding and displaying a name from an array list in a file

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program that uses data from an input file which has been stored into an array so the user can search/find specific names. Right now I am working on the findName method which should take a String and search through all the names (not case-sensitive). If the name is found, the NameRecord is returned, otherwise it returns null. When the user clicks the Find button the event handler (listener) will call findName(), and display the name's ranking for each decade in the JTextArea. However, when I run my program to see if it's working correctly and I push the find button nothing happens. So I believe my problem is that I have either not written my find method correctly or I have done something wrong with my actionlistener, but I think it's my find method. However, I've tried numerous things with my find method, but nothing seems to work. So could someone help/explain what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameSurfer extends JFrame {

  //Declare fields for GUI components
  private NameRecord[] namesArray;
  private JTextArea displayArea;
  private JPanel buttonPanel;
  private JTextField nameField;
  private JButton findButton;
  private JButton matchButton;
  private ButtonListener listener;
  //private GraphPanel graph;
  private JButton graphButton;
  private JButton clearOneButton;
  private JButton clearAllButton;

  /*
  * Constuctor for NameSurfer class
 */
  public NameSurfer() {

    //Build GUI
    super("Name Surfer");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//Set layout
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

//Creates the main panel
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

//Creates the JScrollPane
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane();
displayArea = new JTextArea();
displayArea.setEditable(false);
scroller = new JScrollPane(displayArea);
scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 600));

//Create components
nameField = new JTextField(15);
findButton = new JButton("Find");
matchButton = new JButton("Match");

//Add components to the panel
mainPanel.add(nameField);
mainPanel.add(findButton);
mainPanel.add(matchButton);

//Calls the read method
read("names-data.txt");

findButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

//Add the panel to this JFrame
this.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

//Add scroller to this JFrame
this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//Sizes the frame
this.pack();

//Make the JFrame visible on the screen
this.setVisible(true);
 }

  /**
  *  Method to read input from file
  */
   private void read(String fileName)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     try {
      String inputLine;
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

  int i = 0;
  int num = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine().trim());
  namesArray = new NameRecord[num];

  String inputString;
  while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
    inputString = inFile.nextLine();
    namesArray[i] = new NameRecord(inputString);
    displayArea.append(namesArray[i].toString() + "\n");
  }
  }
 catch(IOException io){
  System.out.print(io);
  }
 }

  /**
 * Method to find name when the find button is pushed
 */
 private NameRecord findName(String targetName)
  {
  int i = 0;
  if (namesArray[i].getName().indexOf(targetName) >= 0)
  {
    displayArea.append(namesArray[i].getName() + "   " );
    i++;
  }

  return namesArray[i];
  }

  /**
  *
   */
   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    findName(nameField.getText());
   }

  }

  /**
  *  The main method creates...
  */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   NameSurfer frame = new NameSurfer();
 }
}
```

Also here is my NameRecord code(if you need it)...

```
 /** Class to hold a name and it's rank over the years
 */
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class NameRecord
 {
   private String name;
   private int[] rank;
   static final int START = 1900;
   static final int DECADES = 12;

 /** Constructor for NameRecord
 *
 * @param nameData string that contains a name and it's rank over the years
 */
  public NameRecord(String nameData) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(nameData);
  name = scan.next();

  //Adds a name's ranked values to the array
  rank = new int[DECADES];
  for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++)
  rank[i] = scan.nextInt();
   }

   /** Accessor method for NameRecord object's name
  *
  * @return value of NameRecord object's name
  */
   public String getName() {
   return name;
   }

  /** Accessor method for NameRecord object's rank
  *
  * @return value of NameRecord object's rank
  */
  public int getRank(int decade) {
   int decadeRank = rank[decade];
    return decadeRank;
  }

  /** returns the best decade
  *
  * @return the best decade
  */
  public int bestDecade() {
    int best = rank[0];
   for(int i=1; i<DECADES; i++)
    if(rank[i] > best)
    best = rank[i];
  return best;
  }

 /**
 * toString method for NameRecord class
 * @return String representation of the NameRecord object
 */
 public String toString() {
 String out = getName();

  //Add name's ranked values to the toString method
  for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++)
  out +=" " + rank[i];

  return out;
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you always find the first one because whenever you press the button then the i will be 0 (i=0)

you should do a for loop to go through all the values when you click the button

```
for(int i = 0;i<namesArray.length;i++){
 if (namesArray[i].getName().indexOf(targetName) >= 0)
  {
    displayArea.append(namesArray[i].getName() + "   " );
    return namesArray[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Same mistake during the reading. The while on the file doesn't increment i. So there is only the first cell that is init.

Comment: When I try this for the findNames method I get an error message that says I'm missing a return statement, but isn't the namesArray[i] my return statement? Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: you have to return null at the end of the method and the error will disappear

Comment: So I added the null and that fixed the error, but when I click on my find button it still isn't displaying anything. Is there something wrong with my listener? I'm really lost on why it isn't working.

Comment: I would suggest to put a breakpoint there and see if it enters that method. and if it enters check where is to problem in the logic. if it's not entering the method just let me know, but as I can see, the listener is implemented correctly

Comment: Sorry I'm asking so many questions, but I'm relatively new to java...Is a breakpoint just the statement break;? Also where am I suppose to put the breakpoint?

Comment: nope, you use breakpoints when you want to debug your code. what IDE are you using? eclipse, netbeans...?

Comment: here's an example how you debug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdUz9OMPWKM

I'd suggest to change your IDE to one of these: Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ